# Narrative options in an antique shop, old bookstore or library

Tags: campaign-development, call-of-cthulhu, trail-of-cthulhu

I'm currently storytelling a Delta Green chronicle and, while studying various resources and scenarios, I was extremely intrigued by a scenario called ["The Bookstore"](https://shadowsofmaine.files.wordpress.com/2008/03/bookst.pdf). That is a great opportunity to give the characters some Cthulhu mythos points and help them get a useful tome or artifact. I would like to extend that scenario and I'm looking for ideas.

In order to extend the question and make it more useful for storytellers:

What tropes do you think fit in an old "Antique Store", "Bookstore" or even "Library"? Do you have any relevant film/comic references (for example, the "Gremlins" movies and "The Occultist" from DC Comics)? Any similar scenarios you've played?

Comment: Hi Astynanax, and welcome to the site! Please check out the [faq] when you get a chance. A bit of advice: we usually do our best when we're answering tightly scoped questions. You'll get much better advice if you're specific about what *you're* trying to accomplish than expanding the question to be more general.

Comment: For example: You say you're looking to extend the scenario... Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Greetings! Concerning the scenario "The Bookstore", the whole concept is that the opening of the tome will summon a guardian creature, the investigators will enter the tiny bookstore (the default map is extremely poor), and then will either copy the marking (trivial with modern (or future) hi-tech) and then dispel the protection, or will destroy the book and the horror will be set free to wreak havoc in-town. So, what more can you do? (continued...)

Comment: Maybe the tome was opened in a hidden room for occult studies. Maybe the characters need the help of an expert "mage". Maybe there is another trap in the book, triggering a travel to the dreamlands (what type of scenario would be fitting then?) Maybe the guardian cannot be unsummoned and thus must be killed after the dispelling is complete (is there a special procedure for this? ;D). Stuff like that, and possible alternative endings to the scenario. Should this be transformed into a "community wiki"?

Comment: We tend to avoid Community Wiki around here, as they generate a lot of noise. We'd much rather help you solve your problem (fleshing out your adventure in this case?) :) What have you considered so far, and why have you ruled it out (or: where did you run into a block)?

Comment: I see... Well, being a junior storyteller, I'd like to see how an experienced keeper would think. So, about what I've thought so far: First of all, the room will indeed be hidden (by magic?). Then, the magic seal cannot be recorded or photographed, you'll have to copy it by eye/hand. Then, the dispel incarnation would need some "essence" of the person who disturbed the seal (that means that the investigators will have to get close to the guardian, being vulnerable to its attacks). A proper dispel is extremely difficult, so the creature will probably be set free instead of being unsummoned.

Comment: Okay, good. Now pick something specific about it that you'd like to know. How players could poke holes in it; how to organize the sequence of events; how to manage the investigations aspects, etc. Split off sub-questions into new questions (by magic? for example). Repeat this process in new questions until you have a feel for what you're trying to find out.

Comment: Yes, in other words factor it into an answerable question rather than "list tropes for a bookstore."

Comment: Also, there's usually folks in chat here that you can noodle around with - sometimes that provides answers, sometimes helps you clarify your thoughts down into concrete questions.

Comment: OK, thanks. If that's the case then I'll probably delete it and phrase a more specific question in a few days.

Comment: Hi Astyanax I've closed this question for now, based on the comments above, and the low-quality answer below. It can be reopened if it's edited into a more focused form. If you have any questions, feel free to drop by [chat].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkheart and Ninth Gate come to mind. Both deal with rare and magical books. This set up can work in so many ways for a Call of Cthulhu adventure. Such as

A bookseller offers the PC money to steal a rare magical text from a secret cult library

While researching in the library one of the PC's goes missing. The only clue is a note they made talking about a book with a demon hand that was crawling on the floor

While in a Antique Store a PC notices a cult figure haggling with the merchant. The next day they find out the merchant was killed and some items where stolen.

Comment: A bit more detail as to why and how they are relevant would be nice.

Comment: I typed more but I guess I hit submit without realizing it